# Replaying Adventure Card?

Tags: savage-worlds

Should you allow the following. Player A use the "my Bennies become XPs" adventure card then, Player B plays "get a card from the Discard stack" and then replays "my Bennies become XPs"?

Comment: Note that this rule was dropped from Core Savage Worlds.  I personally removed it from my adventure deck as well. 
http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26670&sid=948a425d69aefc1de4be190ba78d4795

Comment: Yep I know. Then in the previous version the card would have been useless. I think that the card was added in to Explorers Edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, why not? Isn't that the point of a "get a card from the Discard stack" kind of card?

Comment: Agreed.  Just remember that Player B will need to spend at least 1 benny to play 2 adventure cards.

Comment: Spend a Benny to use a second card, where is that? If you can't use a card to get one from the discard pile and then play it, what is the point of the card?

Comment: See my answer; I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

Per the official rules:

> Players may also trade cards at any time, but this must be a trade—you can never just give them away.
>
> Each player keeps all his cards, but may only play one each game session.

A player can pull a card from the discard pile and trade it to an ally to be played.  This is useful to play that double damage card twice.

If you took the Destiny's Child edge, then you can play two cards per session.

Also, we play by a house-rule of escalating bennies to play extra cards.  Your first card is free to play, the 2nd card costs 1 benny, the 3rd card costs 2 bennies, etc.  I'm not sure where this house rule came from, and only just learned it isn't the official rule.

Comment: You might want to look at this from clint http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34430

Comment: Nice find.  I looked through my adventure card rules and don't see that anywhere; do you know where the source came from?

Comment: sorry no, looking for it myself. But Clint is "the man" so if he say it is must be true.